# expo init <project> throwing unable to verify the first certificate

Tags: expo

I'm using a work machine which is behind a corporate proxy. When I run expo init  I get the below error

```
request to https://registry.npmjs.org/expo-template-blank failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate
FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/expo-template-blank failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/<username>/node_modules/minipass-fetch/lib/index.js:97:14)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:467:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:100:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:68:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

I tried `npm config set ssl-strict=false` but no luck. If i'm missing the certs, then where do I add those? All solutions I see is asking to add some sort of code in the file. But in my case I haven't created a file yet. How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just disabled the proxy and it worked.